# In pandas with lambda functions, TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: lambda, data-science, typeerror, pandas-datareader

Am not sure how to correct this, `un=len(data["investor"].apply(lambda x:x.lower()).unique())`  it gives TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reproduce error, I've built a dummy sample. But I couldn't get the same error that you receive. The result of my code is 10 and it seems to be right.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = np.array(['ab', 'bc', 'bAdd', 'CCdaa', 'absd','aa','ab',6,6,77,888,'888ab']])
data=pd.DataFrame()
data['investor']=a
un=len(data["investor"].apply(lambda x:x.lower()).unique())
```

In order to find which function gives this error you should try following code.

```
print(data["investor"].apply(lambda x:x.lower()))
print(data["investor"].apply(lambda x:x.lower()).unique())
print(len(data["investor"].apply(lambda x:x.lower()).unique()))
```